# How long would it take for a smelly object to evaporate?

Tags: thermodynamics, biophysics, diffusion

This question is a follow on from this deleted one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177894/26076 as I was writing what I thought to be a valid physics answer to it. Version 1 of this question contained essentially this one: if a piece of furniture is smelly, does this not also mean it evaporates? The answer of course is that it does "evaporate", so the question then is "how long would we take to see this?"

So I reworded this question to: how does one calculate the mass loss rate through outgassing from a smelly object?

Comment: Great question. I thought about this in the back of my head since I was a child...

Answer (score 18):

Mammalian sense of smell is in general exquisitely keen: even though we think of ourselves as an animal having a dull smell sense comapared to that of, say, a dog, a pig or a rat, receptors for certain scents are still triggered by molecules counted in the tens. So the outgassing of volatile wood oils from, say, a table, can still be miniscule and well detectable by our sense of smell.

Let's estimate how quickly a table with an odour can evapourate. We can use considerations like those I discuss at the end of [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/166561/26076) and Fick's law to estimate the minimum detectable outgassing rate.

Suppose we have a spherical object sitting at room temperature and pressure. We seek a solution to Fick's law (a wholly mathematical analogous description exists for the diffusion of heat in a conductive medium):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\,t}\phi = D\,\nabla^2\,\phi$$

where $D$, the diffusivity, is derived from considerations of mean free path in gasses and is of the order of $10^{-9}{\rm m^2\,s^{-1}}$ for normal sized molecules in air at room temperature and pressure when the concentration $\phi$ is expressed in moles per cubic meters.

So we seek a spherically symmetric solution and calculate the concentration profile for a given outgassing rate. At steady state, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\,t}=0$ and we have Laplace's equation. The unique spherically symmetric solution is $\phi\propto \frac{1}{r}$. The outgassing rate is given by Fick's first law $\vec{J}=-D\,\nabla\phi$ in moles per second per square meter. With:

$$\phi=\phi_R\,\frac{R}{r}$$

with $R$ the radius of the object and $\phi_R$ the concentration at its surface, we get $\vec{J}=-D\,\mathrm{d}_r\,\phi\,\hat{\vec{r}}$:

$$|J|=-D\,\frac{\phi_R}{R^2}\tag{1}$$

This is the equation we seek. Now, suppose we can detect 100 molecules in each five liter breath. So we can detect about $\phi_R = 100 / (0.005 N_A)$ (about 22.5 liters per mole at room temp and pressure). Let $R=1m$, then $|J| \approx 3\times 10^{-29}{\rm mol\,m^{-2}\,s^{-1}}$, or the sphere is losing $4 \pi |J| = 5\times 10^{-28}{\rm mol\,s^{-1}}$. Work this out as a mass per century and you'll find it's about a femptogram per century!

Comment: +1 I removed the question as I thought it is biology related however thanks a lot I didn't know the law of physics are at work too.

Comment: When you say "a literal handful", I took that to mean "literally as many molecules as could fit in your hand" and thought that wasn't very impressive at all.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for a good answer. Though I will miss the imagery of shoving a literal handful of molecules up my nose and taking a good whiff.

Comment: @user6760 I actually thought it was a good question: i'd never really thought about this before. *Something* is clearly coming out. I think the effect is enhanced insofar that furniture is often *maintained* with things like oil and plasticizers, so real outgassing rates are likely many orders of magnitude above our threshold of detection.

Comment: "Now, suppose we can detect 100 molecules in each five liter breath." This is a very crucial assumption... I am not saying it is false, but some reference for this would improve the answer. But more importantly: this assumes smells move by diffusion only. Based on a very crude Peclet number analysis, it looks like convection is dominant already for an air velocity of 0.1 m/s, so I think this answer underestimates the mass loss by several orders. And this corresponds to real-life experience that wind direction is important if you want to smell something.

Comment: @Pakk I'm sure it does. The analysis you speak of added as a supplementary answer would be a good complement to this one. Obviously as soon as you begin pumping air away and holding concentrations low you'll  raise the outgassing rate. The outgassing rate can be many orders of magnitude greater than calculated and everyday objects would take geological ages to lose significant mass.

Comment: Whatever it is, it will probably lose more mass by being rained upon, shone upon from the sun, and so on. Also some things in that furniture evaporate more than others, so after a (potentially long) while it will smell less (assuming it isn't eaten by bacteria).